# How significant is a good personal website to advance standing in the academic world?

Tags: website

I happen to be close to a professor at my college that has the highest citations of all professors there.  However, his website looks like its from [the 1990's](http://users.wpi.edu/~jsarkis/).  I have some knowledge and motivation to help redesign his website.  However, given that he has an academic business background, and already has significant clout he will almost certainly ask about the value of an improved website.  Is there an article stating the significance of a website, or lack there of?

Comment: (Not exactly a 100% duplicate, maybe, but if reading that discussion does not answer your question I invite you to make it more specific).

Comment: @Federico Poloni It answers some of my question.  I'm more looking for statistics or an article that says "yes there is value" or "no its not significant"

Comment: It probably is from the 1990s, with only incremental updates since then.

Comment: Not really significant

Comment: I imagine this varies with field. The websites of STEM faculty, like their wardrobes, usually don't get updated once they leave grad school.